# Does an overdetermined system always have no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

What is the problem with over-determined systems in linear algebra? Do they always have no solution? Is there a proof of that?

Comment: Overdetermined just means more equations than unknowns. If you duplicate some existing equations, or produce new ones by combining existing ones, you can make any system overdetermined without changing its solution set. So definitely overdetermined does not mean an empty solution set (nor does the converse hold).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An overdetermined system (more equations than unknowns) is **not necessarily** a system with no solution. If one or more of the equations in the system (or one or more rows of its corresponding coefficient matrix) is/are (a) linear combination of the other equations, so the such a system might or might not be inconsistent.

And some systems which are not overdetermined (number of equations = number of unknowns) have no solutions.

What is true is that whenever we have an **inconsistent** system of equations, there is no solution.

My point is that you understand that a system of linear equations has no solution if and only if it is inconsistent.

Comment: and an overdetermined system can have an approximate (least squares) solution, which is very useful.

Comment: You have an example of non-overdetermined system with no solutions ?

Comment: One whose coefficient matrix can be row reduced to a row of the form $0\;0\;0\;|\;b$ where $b$ is nonzero constant, and the system of equations given was three equations three unknowns.

Answer (score 7):

Think of a plane.  Every point has an $x$ and a $y$ component.  A relationship between $x$ and $y$, say $2x = 3y+1$, is a property that some  points have and others do not; $\langle 2,1\rangle$ has this property, and $\langle 0, 0\rangle$ does not.  The set of points with this property forms some curve in the plane; typically a straight line.

Now suppose we have two equations, say  $2x = 3y+1$ and $3x = 2y+4$; there are now two properties we want our points to possess.  The points with one property lie on one line, and the points with the other property lie on another line; if the lines intersect, as they usually do, there will be exactly one point on both lines, and therefore one point that has both properties, and one pair of $x$ and $y$ that satisfies both equations.

If we have three properties, there will be three lines.  The three lines will not usually intersect in the same place:

[image]

There will be a point with properties $A$ and $B$, a point with properties $A$ and $C$, and a point with properties $B$ and $C$.  But no point will have all three properties because no point lies on all three lines.

Sometimes the three lines will all intersect in the same place.  Then the three equations have a solution:

[image]

For example, $$\begin{align}2x&=3y+1\\
3x &= 2y+4\\
x &= y+1
\end{align}$$

all intersect at the point $\langle 2,1\rangle$. So it can happen sometimes, but not always.