# Solving m equations in n unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

While taking Prof.Gilbert Strang linear algebra class, I encounter a problem, if we have 3x2 matrix A and right hand side vector 3x1. Here m>n,  So the solution exists only if the right hand side in the column space of A, but somehow I am not able to visualize how is that even possible, we solve any two equations simultaneously and we get a solution, but there may be a case that solution does not satisfy the third equation. I am not able to visualize or grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the type $Ax = b$, where $A$ is your $3 \times 2 $ matrix. Then you are saying that $b$ is of size $3 \times 1$, so this means that $x$ is of size $2 \times 1$.

Now, notice that the following statements are equivalent (if one of them is true then *all* of them are true, if one is false then *all* of them are false) :

1. For every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the equation $Ax = b$ has a solution.
2. The columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$.
3. Each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Afterwards, there are many ways of solving systems of linear equations: substitution, elimination, Gauss-Jordan. By using these methods you are assured to find a solution that works for all your variables (or the lack of a possible solution).

In your case, you would have a resulting system with $3$ equations and $2$ unknowns, which is known as an overdetermined system. If you want to know *when* they have a solution read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007337/481192)